# Swift Saving score using CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My app is based on score, and thats the only thing i have to save in the CoreData, one instance of Score, a single Integer. Everytime i am trying, it fails. My app will load the Data when the app loads, and save new data when the app is closed. Note that im only in need of **one** single Integer stored. Is the best way to do this by using CoreData, or something else? Every thread i read, is saying different things. So now im asking, how whould i do this, using CoreData (If thats the best way).

Comment: Could you provide your code? You more than likely need to wrap your integer in NSNumber.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487258/sending-float-to-parameter-of-incompatible-type-id/31487847#31487847

Comment: @AlexBlair Oh, so that was the problem, Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data is **SERIOUS** overkill for storing a single integer. It's like firing up an F16 fighter jet in order to go around the corner to buy a loaf of bread. It will get you there in a hurry, but you need a LOT of specialized knowledge in order to know how to use it.

Just save your Int to `UserDefaults` and be done with it. That is a much better tool for the task you have.